# using google driving direction api

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

[image]I am making an app in which there are two option

- 1."Give Ride"
- 2."Need Ride".

  For example,

USER-A has selected "Give Ride" option then he has to enter some info like

"FROM:(StartLat and StartLong)" "TO:(EndLat and EndLong)" using textView.

This info will store.

Now USER-B select other option "Need Ride". He has to enter too same info like before "FROM:(InputStartLat and InputStartLong)" "TO:(InputEndLat and InputEndLong)".

***Now App will start searching to find a matching route for USER-B. If USER-A's route matching with USER-B's then search result will display as names of USERS who select option 1."Give Ride***

I want to create new route and assign record in new route if source and destination radius < 7km

Comment: ok. then what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I have positions table which has 7 columns
**id | source | destination | source_lat | source_lng | dest_lat | dest_lng**

I want to register unique route suppose user A, user B and user C travel under radius 5 km so I want to create a route and insert user A,B and C route so How can I implement. what is the best Idea?